# CSS to have some space around when tabbing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way with CSS to have some space around the focused element, in order to view around it?
If not, what can be a non intrusive javascript?
Thanks

```html
(please use keyboard tab)<br>
when tabbing... 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
did you notice me?<br><br>
<span tabindex=1>I want to be a bit far from viewport TOP and BOTTOM borders</span><br><br>
and me?<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<span tabindex=2>I want the same</span><br>
at least to see this!!!<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

**Edit**:
Similar to what was suggested, this partialy solves question:

```
span {
  padding-top: 70px;     /* guaranties to see the text above */
  padding-bottom: 70px;  /* guaranties to see the text below */ 
  /* but both produce a big focus rectangle around */
  outline-offset: -70px; /* this helps a little on FF */
}
```

This works perfect in FF but not in IE:

```
span       {padding-top: 70px; padding-bottom: 70px;}
span:focus {padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;}
```

Comment: add a class to your spans

Comment: @artm yes, a class with which property?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hjm9c9re/1/

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're asking, but something like this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjm9c9re/)

You can make your element a block element  (instead of an inline span element) and add padding with css on the `:focus` selector

```
// css
div:focus {padding-left: 10px;}

// html
<div tabindex=1>test</div>
<div tabindex=2>lorem</div>
<div tabindex=2>ipsum/div>
```

The div which currently has the focus will have the above CSS style applied to it. You can change the div:focus selector to a class, something like:

```
.my-class:focus {padding-left: 10px;}
```

And then add that class to your elements

Answer (score 1):

Use the :focus pseudo-class in your css.

```
<span tabindex=1 class="expandsOnFocus">Bla bla</span>
```

In css

```
.expandsOnFocus:focus {
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :focus pseudo-class and tabindex attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            section > * { margin: 0; }
            section > *:focus { margin: 20px 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <p tabindex="1">First paragraph</p>
            <p tabindex="2">Second paragraph</p>
            <p tabindex="3">Third paragraph</p>
            <input type="text" name="in" value="" />
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

For old IE versions (if you need to support them), you can try a fix: [Fixing “:focus” in Internet Explorer](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/).

Comment: thanks! and sorry but this is not the case. Here are all <br> missing (i did added on my test of your anwser). The point is to have the element with focus and 1-do not alter document layout, 2-have the focused element far from top and bottom viewport borders when tabbing.